# Prove that $\int\limits_1^\infty\frac{e^x}{x^{x^2}}dx$ converges

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

I need to prove that the following improper integral converges:
$$\int\limits_1^\infty\frac{e^x}{x^{x^2}}dx$$

I can't find a function to compare with it in order to use the integral comparison test or the limit comparison test.

Comment: Hint: $f(x)=e^{\ln(f(x))}$

Comment: Hint: For $x>e$, $x^{x^2}>e^{x^2}$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: For $x \ge e$, $\dfrac {e^x} {x^{x^2}} < e^{-x}$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $c$ be such that $c^c=e$. Then, $\int_1^\infty e^x/x^{x^2}dx=\int_1^\infty (e/x^x)^xdx=\int_1^{c+\varepsilon} (e/x^x)^xdx+\int_{c+\varepsilon}^\infty (e/x^x)^xdx$ converges, since for $x\ge c+\epsilon$, we have $e/x^x\le e/(c+\epsilon)^{c+\epsilon}<1$.